# My timer won't work in Unity

Tags: unity

In my game, you can spawn a cube by clicking. After 10 seconds I want the cube to disappear. That's what I'm trying to do in my code but it won't work:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class circleThing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject circle;
    public GameObject block;
    public float time;
    void Start() {
         Vector3 temp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         temp.z = 5f;
         transform.position = temp;
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             StartCoroutine(timer());
             Instantiate(block, temp, Quaternion.identity);
         }
         if (time >= 10) {
             Destroy(block);
         }
    }
    void Update()
    {
      
    }
     IEnumerator timer(){

        while (true)
        {
            Debug.Log(time);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            time++;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the error: `Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, **you are not using `Instantiate` correctly**. You pass in a `GameObject` (and other data) and it returns a copy.

In your code, you are not instantiating an object and setting it to `block`, you are instantiating a copy of `block` (which is nothing at this point I assume since you are not assigning anything to it in your code snippet) and not storing the returned `GameObject` in anything:

```
Instantiate(block, temp, Quaternion.identity);
```

What you need to do is create a variable that stores a `Prefab` cube that you then `Instantiate` and assign to block:

```
public GameObject circle;
    public GameObject CubePrefab; // use the Inspector to assign a cube prefab here
    public GameObject block;
    public float time;
    void Start()
    {
         Vector3 temp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         temp.z = 5f;
         transform.position = temp;
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             StartCoroutine(timer());
             block = Instantiate(CubePrefab, temp, Quaternion.identity);
         }
         [...]
```

or you can create a primitive `Cube` and manipulate its position/rotation:

```
[...]
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    StartCoroutine(timer());
    block = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    block.transform.position = temp;
    block.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
}
[...]
```

As for your destroy method, unless you are trying to learn `Coroutine`s, I would suggest you just use the built-in delay parameter in the signature for the `Destroy` method (as you already determined), which you would do immediately after creating the object:

```
block = Instantiate(CubePrefab, temp, Quaternion.identity);
Destroy(block, 10);
```

or alternatively you can do something like this:

```
public float blockCreateTime;
[...]
void Update()
{
    [...]
    block = Instantiate(CubePrefab, temp, Quaternion.identity);
    blockCreateTime = Time.time;
    [...]
    if (blockCreateTime - Time.time > 10)
    {
        Destroy(block);
    }
    [...]
}
```

I don't like that way of doing it, just letting you know that you can track time without creating a "timer" `Coroutine`.

**As a little disclaimer**, I haven't tried doing any of the above, that's just how `Instantiate` and `GameObject.CreatePrimitive` work. Also, in case you didn't know, `Time.time` will return how long the game has been running, so the check above subtracts the current duration the game has been running from the duration stored when you created the `block` to see if it is greater than the threshold (in this case 10s).

Comment: I found that out, but thanks for you're answer

Comment: @c0d3r yeah, I realized that after I posted the answer, but I figured I'd leave it up for informational purposes for anyone else looking to do something similar since your answer didn't explain the core issue, and mine has some alternatives.

Comment: I decided to look back at this answer and I realized you put a better way to use a timer. Thanks for that, because couritene wasn't working too well.

Comment: @c0d3r no problem, happy to help! As awesome as Coroutines are, I often find that while I'm eager to use them, I need to stop and rethink if there's a simpler way to do them.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is just this:

````cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

public class circleThing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject circle;
    public GameObject block;
    public float time;
    GameObject newBlock;
    void Start() {
         
    }
    void Update()
    {
      Vector3 temp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         temp.z = 5f;
         transform.position = temp;
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             newBlock = Instantiate(block, temp, Quaternion.identity);
         }
             Destroy(newBlock, 10);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: You can move the Destroy inside the `if` so you don't call `Destroy` when there's nothing to be destroyed. You can also remove the empty `Start` function, make `newBlock` a local variable, and name your class with an initial uppercase letter to match the standard nomenclature.

Comment: The reason your earlier code wasn't working was you put it all in `Start`, which only runs once, the frame the object first spawns. So it won't be running a frame later when you click, or 10 seconds later when you want to destroy the block. By moving this code to `Update`, which runs every frame, you make sure you can detect a click no matter when it happens.